# Wait related -selenium Java code executes the next command ,eventhough the page as not loaded as per the previous command

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
driver2.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("password123");
driver2.findElement(By.id("btnLogon")).click();
driver2.findElement(By.id("Process_navItem")).click();
driver2.findElement(By.id("revit_navigation_NavItem_0")).click();
```

The 4th line of the code gets executed, though the page has not loaded as per the third line code. Thus it fails.

Please suggest some wait method in a simple code as am a fresher.

Comment: This might be a issue of AJAX calls...perform as suggested by @Helping Hands

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit wait before 4th line of your code :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You can increase seconds in above code. I have set 30 seconds.

If above wait do not work then you can use wait as per below also :

```
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("revit_navigation_NavItem_0")));
```